# What is the Italian term for a packet (of paper) used by a teacher?

Tags: single-words

Often in school in the US teachers prepare collections of photocopied notes and exercises to give to students. They are usually bound by a single staple in the corner. I'm not entirely sure of whether this practice exists in Italy, but as a teacher in the US, I am often looking for this term.

The closest that I have found is *fascicolo*, but I wonder if this is closer to the English *dossier* which would not be accurate.

Can somebody who went to school in Italy provide me with the appropriate term for this?

Comment: In Spanish and in Catalan, we say *dossier*, but I don't know which is the term in Italian.

Comment: Interesting ... *dossier* in English usually refers to a file the government (or other entity) puts together about your activities when they want to build a legal case against you.

Comment: "Dossier" is used as a loan word also in Italian, with the same meaning you described (not necessarily governmental, could be related to journalism or medical facts), i.e. a set of information about a topic/individual. A generic collective noun for a set of related "paper copies" of something/sheets of paper is a "plico" (plico di fotocopie). The more precise one, related to education, is "dispensa", as pointed out in an answer below

Answer (score 13):

I believe  that the proper term is ***[dispensa](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/D/dispensa.shtml)***, sometimes used in the plural form which is *dispense*.

> - (dispensa universitaria,) sintesi delle lezioni tenute da un docente durante l'anno accademico. (Sabatini Colletti)

By the way, I've only seen this happening when I was a university student.

Comment: I'll add that the English term *handout* is gaining traction inside the university (funnily enough I've heard it very often but only from humanities students)

Comment: @DenisNardin I've never heard about it.

Comment: I think it's referring to sheets of paper containing long extracts of the text or photos of inscrptions that is analyzed during a seminar, so that the audience can follow what's going on (the friends that told me are for the most part in phylology or epigraphy)

Comment: In Australia, we wouldn't understand "packet of paper" - handout certainly though! Most likely  I'd assume

Answer (score 2):

I'm Italian and I don't know terms for your description. When I went to the pre-university school teachers give rarely photocopies. I remember some generic terms like 'schede' for example.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: I have also heard the term *scheda* used to refer to a *handout*, but not a collection of handouts

Comment: I've heard *schede* or even *fogli* (!) to describe long handouts, often of several pages

Answer (score 2):

In elementary school and middle school, they are referred as *schede*. In high school the term *fotocopie* is much more common.

This is because thinking about the teacher giving you a *scheda* might even make you feel childish or something, although this is subjective.

At the university, a handout is almost always called *dispensa*.